# Executable cannot access an environment variable, but it can if launched from Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, environment-variables

```
string root = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ROOT").
```

When I launch the program from Visual Studio root is the expected directory. However, when launching it myself (with or without admin privilege), root is undefined.

If I write the result in a log file, this is what it looks like :

---

Launch from Visual Studio :

Begin log

Accessing root directory
....

---

Launch it myself :

Begin log

Root is not defined!
......

**Edit** : This env variable is defined in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Control\Session Manager\Environment".

It shows up when I type SET in the prompt. It doesn't show up when I access the enviroment variables
from Computer->Properties->Advanced Settings.

The program is supposed to work on machines that have same settings, thus the users won't define the variables themselves (which would make the environment accessible to the program).

Comment: have you defined this variable yourself?

Comment: I've added more details to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the environment variable is not defined for the user the process is running under.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

There are system and user specific environment variables.

You can type `env` (or `set`) at the prompt to list what's set and what isn't.